# Do Axios request with SQL array

Tags: mysql, express, async-await, axios, routes

I'm trying to query mySQL database inside Express route, get an array called "subjects", then run axios request with the array. Then I want to display the responses on EJS.

Such as,

```js
// for-each "subject", 
    var url = `http://news.com/${subject}`
    const articles_get =await axios.get(url)
    res.render('news',{articles:articles_get.data.articles})
```

I tried so many things, I keep getting errors about "async/await must be at the top level" and "HEADERS ALREADY SENT". I tried following other examples on SO but none have worked. I think I'm missing some idea. Please any help is appreciated!

Here's my current code that says "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"
I tried to move the function out of the route, then call it inside the route, but it just never returned anything.

```js
app.get("/mySubjects", (req, res) => {
  var subjects = [];
  var username = req.body["username"];

  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM mySubjects WHERE username = ?",
    [username],
    async function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      if (results.length > 0) {
        results.forEach((result) => {
          subjects.push(result.subject);
        });

        subjects.forEach((subject) => {
          //call NEWS API FOR EACH SUBJECT
          try {
            var url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?category=${subject}apiKey=c7777777777777`;

            const news_get = await axios.get(url);
            res.render("news", { articles: news_get.data.articles });
          } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.status(401).send({ message: "Nothing is here." });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `res.render()` **once** as it will render your template and respond to the client. What you need to do is collect all your data first, then render your template.

For example

```js
if (results.length > 0) {
  // using Promise.allSettled so it doesn't bail at the first failed request
  const allResults = await Promise.allSettled(
    results.map(async ({ subject }) => {
      const { data: { articles } } = await axios.get("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources", {
        params: { // params is the easy way to pass query parameters
          category: subject,
          apiKey: "c7777777777777",
        }
      });
      return { subject, articles };
    })
  );

  // Extract all the successful responses
  const allArticles = allResults
    .filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled")
    .map(({ value }) => value);

  // render your template
  res.render("news", { allArticles });

  // optionally log the failed requests
  allResults
    .filter(({ status }) => status === "rejected")
    .forEach(({ reason }) => {
      console.error(reason.response?.data ?? reason.message)
    })
} else {
  // 401 is for Unauthorized, use 404 for Not Found
  res.status(404).send({ message: "Nothing is here." });
}
```

This will render your `news` template, passing a property named `allArticles` which is an array of objects with `subject` and `articles` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should not send a response inside forEach since it has not done iterating.

The example below will return all `response.data` as an array and make sure you handle them accordingly in ejs file.

```js
app.get('/mySubjects', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body['username'];

  connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM mySubjects WHERE username = ?',
    [username],
    function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;

      if (results.length > 0) {
        const requests = results.map(({ subject }) =>
          axios.get(
            `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?category=${subject}apiKey=c7777777777777`,
          ),
        );
        Promise.all(requests)
          .then((news) => {
            res.render('news', { news });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // Handle error
            console.log(err.message);
          });
      } else {
        res.status(401).send({ message: 'Nothing is here.' });
      }
    },
  );
});
```